# Rebuild javacv.jar for Android

Tags: android, javacv, javacpp

I hate to sound like a n00b but I have been trying to figure this out for several hours now and could really use some help. I have successfully been able to use FFmpeg and OpenCV in my Android app by using javacv.jar and javacpp.jar provided [here](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.4-cppjars.zip&can=2&q=). This has been working great, but there has been some changes to [javacv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/detail?r=87516e8715d40c73e9e0e7ea65da70e345aa3498) and [javacpp](https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/source/detail?r=3934c45285d7de75c7c827b3a104cbe89658d6aa) and I need to rebuild these for my app. I have checked out both of these repositories to my home directory. I also have opencv-2.4.4 in my home directory. I was able to compile javacpp and get a jar file by running "mvn install" in the javacpp directory. When I try to do this in my javacv directory, I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JavaCV
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:properties {execution: properties}]
[INFO] [dependency:copy-dependencies {execution: copy-dependencies}]
[INFO] javacpp-0.4.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: javacpp}]
Generating source file:     /home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/jnicvkernels.cpp
Building library file: /home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/linux- x86_64/libjnicvkernels.so
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include /home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/jnicvkernels.cpp  -msse3 -ffast-math -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/ -march=x86-64 -m64 -Wall -O3 -fPIC -shared -s -o   /home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/linux-x86_64/libjnicvkernels.so - L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jamvm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk- amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jamvm -ljvm 
In file included from   /home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/jnicvkernels.cpp:58:0:
/home/marwfair/javacv/target/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/cvkernels.h:22:33: fatal error:   opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have read the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Instructions_for_Android) for javacpp for Android and the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) for javacv. I am running Ubuntu and am pretty new to Maven. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I am really missing some key points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, missed a pretty key point. I didn't have OpenCV installed on my computer. I was able to build the file after following this [guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) to install OpenCV.